# Arduino Nano 33 IoT & NEO 6M GPS Module

Tags: c++, arduino, gps, connection

I am having trouble getting connection between Arduino Nano 33 IoT and NEO 6M GPS module.

I tried this connection:

Arduino 33 IOT RX0 -> Neo TX,

Arduino 33 IOT TX1 -> Neo RX,

Arduino 33 IOT 3.3V -> Neo VCC,

Arduino 33 IOT GND -> Neo GND,

With this sketch:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ccDY.jpg)

Once the sketch is uploaded, I do not see any NMEA message in the com serial. Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is nothing in your sketch to read Serial1 and send to Serial. see the SerialPassthrough example

Comment: I tried testing with the sketch below but the serial com is producing ---> ????????
Is it because I'm testing it indoors?

#include <TinyGPS++.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial1.write(Serial.read());
  }

  if (Serial1.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial1.read());
  } 
}

Comment: at what baud rate sends data the GPS module?

Comment: Baud rate at 9600

Comment: and did you set 9600 baud in Serial Monitor?

Comment: Yes both are at 9600. 

Yet the com serial is just generating the message: 


???????????